# php get_meta_tags not fetching property="og:type" tags

Tags: php, function, web, meta-tags

so php's get_meta_tags would fetch the meta tags that has a name field to it but sometimes there are meta tags that has no fields but uses property="" as identifier instead and this function is not fetching it....

is there any better way to get meta tags including those with property="" identifiers in php?

Comment: Use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the XML or HTML yourself with DOM's loadHTML and run an xpath on it.