# Meta keyword and description REG EX issue

Tags: php, regex

Im writing a program to pull the meta info from websites.

I need to write some regex to pull the text in the between the content tags.

```
$find = "<meta\s+name=['\"]??keywords['\"]??\s+content=['\"]??(.+)['\"]??\s*\/?>";
```

This works ok for meta keywords written like so:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword, keyword, keyword" /> or like so
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword, keyword, keyword">
```

BuT I would like to flip it round so it can find the text inbetween the content tags in this format:

```
<meta content="keyword, keyword, keyword" name="keywords" /> or like so
<meta content="keyword, keyword, keyword" name="keywords" >
```

Anyone help? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you could also use [`get_meta_tags()`](http://php.net/get_meta_tags) - a builtin PHP function which extracts `<meta>` tag attributes from websites (or already downloaded files):

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');
print_r($tags);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea there was a function for this

Comment: +1 @mario, thanks for spotting this function. Tough it seems not so reliable as DOM/xpath. See following discussions : 
http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/2516-get_meta_tags-expects-unique-name-values
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894068/php-get-meta-tags-not-fetching-property-ogtype-tags

FYI, I also experienced stability issues with other PHP `url functions` such as `parse_url`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<meta[^>]*content="(?<keyword>[^"]*)"[^>]*/?>
```

---

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [PHP DOm](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlcontent);
$xpath= new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist=$xpath->query('//meta[@name='keywords']/@content');
foreach($nodelist as $node)
  echo $node->nodeValue;
```

Using regexp works most of the time but it can not work safely on any HTML content.